# Where do I put custom code to handle a resize event C# windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I cannot work out where to put nor get the code to trigger when my main form windows are resized (ie minimize button clicked)

I am trying to trigger this code when ANY resize of the DigiDocketMain window is minimized etc, or also how I can specifically code the minimize button to do something - the ideal goal is to get the program - n minimize button click to hide the taskbar icon and show a tray icon.

I have tried placing this is the main code body and the designer code but nothing triggers it. any help would be appreciated.

```
 private void DigiDocketMain_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.ResizeEnd event.");
             if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized)
             {
                 this.Hide();
                 mainTrayIcon.Visible = true;
             }
         }
```

Comment: Did you subscribe to the `Resize` event? `Resize += new EventHandler(DigiDocketMain_Resize);`

Comment: By designer, click you winform and navigate to property window. Click on a lightning symbol (for events ) and click on Resize for adding it.

Comment: Ok very new to this,
I have not subscribed to resize event - will see how to do so - any code examples
and will also look at the designer way. Thanks for the pointers - first windows form coding

Comment: Ok this has shed the light necessary - thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

In your code behind add the following to the Form_Load Event

```
this.SizeChanged += Form1_SizeChanged;
```

Then implement the function, autocomplete may do this for you.

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add the code that will be called on resize events.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, when clicking the minimize button, you want to hide the
taskbar icon and display the tray icon.

I suggest that you set the Visible of notifyIcon1 to false in the property bar, and select a icon format image as the icon, then try the following code.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                this.Hide();
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            }

        }

        private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;

        }
    }
```